# format json for loading remote data select2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I try to apply the example of Select2 in loading remote data, but do not quite understand how it should be the json format.

Using this example:

```
    $(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "http://localhost:8081/pruebas/select2/examples/jsondata.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
      params.page = params.page || 1;
      return {
        results: data.items,
        pagination: {
          more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
        }
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, 
  minimumInputLength: 1,
});
```

My json has the following format:

```
[{"id":0,"text":"Wilmer Hilaquita"},{"id":1,"text":"Juana de Arco"}]
```

When you start the search, ajax sent me this message:

```
GET http://localhost:8081/pruebas/select2/examples/jsondata.php?q=Wil
```

Json not find anything, let me know if sending the json should receive it as a parameter $ _GET and work in the json with that parameter, considering that my data are higher than 60000 records

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need pagination you can simplify `processResults` function and have something like:

```
processResults: function (data, params) {
   return  { 
      results: data 
   };
}
```

(this assuming that `data` is an array of objects having `id` and `text` properties). If this is not the case, inside the same function you need to process your response in order to get the same type of array.